# Valid HTML code not interpreted as HTML in PhpStorm 9

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 9.0 I created a file "index.html", pasted a valid code into it and saw it interpreted with plenty of errors.
Then I created another one, named "abc.html" - pasted same code and saw it interpreted as HTML.
Then I deleted the former "index.html" and renamed "abc.html" to "index.html" - again, it got interpreted not as html - can't really see as what.

Can anyone please tell me what's giving? Where in the Settings could I verify or force the right interpreter in?

---

When I start typin in the offending file, the autocomplete menu mentions lib.d.ts, so I think PhpStorm is interpreting the file as TypeScript.

[image]

Comment: Showing said valid could would be of great help to solving this problem.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac You're right - here it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | File Types`
2. Locate entry for `TypeScript` files
3. Delete offending pattern there -- most likely will be "index.html" or very similar.

Comment: Exactly. But how the heck did it happen?

Comment: Most likely misclick somewhere. Or another likely approach (at least it's the reason in most cases): you have created new file called `index` (note no extension), IDE asked what language/file type it should be associated with .. and you have selected TypeScript. Then you have added extension (renamed the file, basically) but it was too late...